# Why aren't the hydrogen bonds in carboxyllic acids like this?

Tags: organic-chemistry, carbonyl-compounds, hydrogen-bond

Why don't carboxylic acids form H-bonds in this formation with the red dots (diagonal) instead of the black dots (horizontal)?

[image: carboxylic acid hydrogen bonding scenarios]

I was always taught that H-bonds formed between partially negative and partially positive atoms. I agree that the $\ce{=O}$ carboxyl oxygen is partially negative, so there should be a H-bond there from the partially positive H.

However, the $\ce{O}$ in $\ce{OH}$ is also partially negative. So why aren't the H-bonds denoted with red dots formed?

Comment: And nobody told you that it goes straight to **lone pair**?

Comment: So, while bifurcated hydrogen bonds *do* exist, it's not the case here.

Comment: Does the red-dotted line from the hydrogen lead to electron pairs on oxygen? I think not.

Comment: You need some degree of orbital overlap. Pretty challenging to overlap at that kind of angle.

Comment: In reality in carboxylic acids, there are no double bond and single bond on oxygens. It is a hybrid (e.g., where is the $\ce{^{13}C}$-signal for carboxylic carbonyl in NMR?).

Comment: Often times you ignore the stuff that is not as important. It's a simple cartoon after all.

Comment: @MathewMahindaratne Isn't that just an issue with fast exchange in NMR? I would think that the oxygens are inequivalent (in a carboxylic acid in general; in the picture shown here for paired groups the inequivalence of the oxygens is less clear).

Comment: H-bonds are indeed *bonds*, and your black dotted lines give a 6-ring, and with the red, it´s a 4-ring. If you want to know for sure, check the crystal structure of any carboxylic acid.

Comment: @Mithoron but isn't there a lone pair on the red bond oxygen?

Comment: And what does "straight to" mean? - Lone pair is no the *other* side of oxygen.

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/60640/why-cant-alcohols-form-hydrogen-bonded-dimers-like-carboxylic-acids