# O-C-O bond angles in carboxylates vs carboxylic acids?

Tags: organic-chemistry, molecular-structure, carboxylic-acids

I am wondering how different the O-C-O angle is in a carboxylate vs its acid form.

Does it (noticeably) increase because of the electron-electron repulsion caused by an additional lone pair?

Bond lengths are given [here](https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Organic_Chemistry/Organic_Chemistry_(McMurry)/20%3A_Carboxylic_Acids_and_Nitriles/20.02%3A_Structure_and_Properties_of_Carboxylic_Acids), but angles are mentioned only when discussing neutral acid (giving 122°).

Comment: Not a proper answer, but the O-C-O bond angle in a given carboxylate depends also on their counterion. In aqueous solution you may have the free carboxylate or some form of a metal carboxylate complex. In the solid dry state of a metal carboxylate, it will be  different than in solution. I also would assume that the O-C-O bond angle in dissolved, neutral carboxylic acids depends on the solvent as well as their concentration, as they tend to form dimers. Could you specify a little more what exactly you are interested in?

Comment: This answer might help you: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/60645/17368